# How can I run grunt as a daemon?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, command-line-interface, daemon, epub

I am running a packaged nodejs webserver that allows for reading of epub files ([Readium-JS](https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer)), and it is started with the grunt command.

However, if I run this on my VPS the server dies as soon as my terminal connection ends.

How can I run this task as a daemon?

I have looked at options like grunt-forever and grunt-daemon but the way the Gruntfile is written using load-grunt-config is messing with my mind and I can't piece together how to isolate the server code.

Comment: Do you really need to start it with grunt? [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) is the most popular process manager but I don't know that it'd work with grunt.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that calling grunt from the command line is necessary. There doesn't seem to be a file that I can run 'node file.js' that will boot up the server correctly, otherwise I would have thrown it together with forever already. It seems grunt is pulling together the configuration and then booting it, which doesn't seem to be called from anything other than running grunt. --- That said, I have tried it out and it seems to be working. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

As was suggested above, using [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

However, when I ran

```
pm2 start grunt
```

I got an error saying that the grunt module did not exist, which was weird.

So I ended up writing a script which worked:

-- start.js --

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function() {
  pm2.start({
    script    : '/usr/local/bin/grunt',         // Script to be run
    args: '--force',
  }, function(err, apps) {
    pm2.disconnect();
  });
});
```

After running node start.js from the command line, everything sailed smoothly.